# Regex replace uppercase by lower and put underscore

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text and I want to change this kind of string :

```
ShouldHavePageRequestAndSpecificationsNot
```

to :

```
should_have_page_request_and_specifications_not
```

And I just find this :

Find what :

```
(([a-z][A-Z]+)|([A-Z]+[a-z]))
```

Replace with :

```
\L$1
```

Only uppercase are going lower, I tried to insert "_" but failed all tests..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Case Conversion](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Case%20Conversion) plugin. It adds a number of options to the **`Edit -> Convert Case`** menu, including PascalCase and snake_case, which is what you're looking for here. Just select what you want to convert, go to the menu, and select what you want to convert to. There are keyboard shortcuts attached to each of the conversions, which should be listed on the menu.

Answer (score 3):

Use 'Case Sensitive' and 'regular expression' with these: (worked for me)

Find what :

```
([a-zA-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z])
```

Replace with :

```
\L\1_\L\2
```

(use "Replace All")